# Completely remove / delete a div and show another (toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a div completely delete itself not just set the style to none for example, I am wondering if it's possible to completely remove and show another, but toggle so that it can be retrieved still. Is this possible using html. Would loading it off another file be the only solution?

At the moment I'm redirecting the user depending on their select to a new page but I'm wanting it all on the same page ideally but that it updates completely.

```
function showDiv(elem) {
   if (elem.value == 19) {
     // show div 1
     // delete div 2 completely
   } else if(elem.value == 20) {
     // show div 2
     // delete div 1 completely
   }
}
```

Comment: If you delete a div completely, you can't recover it without recreating it. What's wrong with hiding it?

Comment: I removed both php and html tags, since there was no relevance and code attached to the post. Until you can show relevance, the tags should not be used. You can add those back in after you've shown relevance and code.

Comment: I can imagine if someone doesn't want to load all content right away (speed, SEO, etc) and fetch more later, but you want to load all content first (div1+2), then discard some of it... then want it back again? Well, look into using ajax.

Comment: You're looking for [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this on client side, you can use template approach:

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  var value = elem.value;
  var templateId = 'template' + value;
  var containerId = 'main-container';
  var template = document.getElementById(templateId);
  var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  if (template && container) {
    container.innerHTML = template.textContent;
  }
}

showDiv({value: 19});
```

```html
<select onchange="showDiv(this)">
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
</select>

<div id="main-container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="template19">
  <div>Content 19</div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="template20">
  <div>Content 20</div>
</script>
```